# Why can't I use Linq Select in subclass of List<string> using base.Select?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I instantiate my subclass of `List<string>`, then I can use Linq's `Select` method.

```
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BetterList list = new BetterList();
            list.Select(l => l.ToString() == "abc");  // no compile error
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try to use Select within the definition of the subclass...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqProblem
{
    class BetterList : List<string>
    {
        public List<string> Stuff
        {
            get
            {
                base.Select(l => l.ToString() == "abc");  // compile error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> '`List<string>`' does not contain a definition for 'Select'.

Why is this the case, and is there a work-around?

Comment: There usually isn't much good reason to inherit from `List<T>`, are you sure this is the _best_ way to accomplish your needs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/34397

Comment: @maccettura, I did so because I wanted to add properties that can act as filters - shorthand code for the Linq logic. The code I'm writing will be used by a team, and readability is very important. Is there a better way to achieve the same end?

Comment: Oh I also want to check when an item is added whether there's already an item with the same "key" property. If so, I have logic that handles adding a "duplicate" item sensibly. I did so by overriding the Add method.

Comment: It sounds like you might want a Dictionary instead of a List.  Dictionarys cannot have duplicate keys, it will throw an exception if you try.  Also, you should create a class that has a private Dictionary or List as the data store, then expose the date via methods or properties (do your filtering there)

Comment: @maccettura that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Select()` is an extension method.  The `base` keyword is specifically used to non-virtually call base class methods, and does not support extension methods.

Change it to `this.Select` and it will work fine.